# How can i change the text with include html tag in json array? (Vue.js)

Tags: javascript, html, css, json, vue.js

I want to change the text to html tags.
What i want to do is highlighting search keyword.
So i need to wrap matched word with html tags in  raw Data.

Here is example json.
I tried several ways. However, after changed, it is displayed as a plain text.

```
var json=[
  {
    "_id": "5cde61fca408de046c88c019",
    "timestamp": "Fri Oct 13 1978 12:44:39 ",
    "hostname": "Rowe",
    "rawLog": "Nulla sit nisi officia anim deserunt do."
  },
  {
    "_id": "5cde61fcb09db1ad8926dda6",
    "timestamp": "Sat May 08 1999 09:08:12 ",
    "hostname": "West",
    "rawLog": "Non Lorem cupidatat officia tempor incididunt aliquip fugiat cupidatat nulla officia."
  }
]
```

```
json[1].rawData='Nulla sit nisi'+ '<b style="color:red;">officia</b>'+ 'anim deserunt do';
```

I tried like this.

I want vue read 'officia' as html tags.

Is there any solution?

Thank you.

Comment: How have you tied to do it so far? You can [parse XML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Parsing_and_serializing_XML).

Comment: Is this what you are trying to do? https://jsfiddle.net/Ljq0dywd/

Comment: @Alicia Thank you for your comments. It was too difficult to me. But i really appreciate your help.

Comment: @emcee22 Thank you for your comment. I solve the problem with your way, v-html.